# pip install mysqlclient failed "Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error"

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, macos, pipenv

I'm trying to run my Python 3 project on my newly formatted Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.4, by first running `pipenv install` to get the dependencies, but that fails.

Specifically, the part where it fails to install dependencies is the mysqlclient part.

This error message shows up:

```
_mysql.c:1894:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
              my_bool recon = reconnect;
              ^
_mysql.c:1895:58: error: use of undeclared identifier 'recon'
              mysql_options(&self->connection, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &recon);
                                                                     ^
```

### Configuration

```
darrenkarlsapalo@admins-MacBook-Pro ~/g/t/thesis-nltk> python --version
Python 2.7.10

darrenkarlsapalo@admins-MacBook-Pro ~/g/t/thesis-nltk> python3 --version
Python 3.6.5

darrenkarlsapalo@admins-MacBook-Pro ~/g/t/thesis-nltk> brew install mysql-connector-c
Warning: mysql-connector-c 6.1.11 is already installed, its just not linked
You can use `brew link mysql-connector-c` to link this version.

darrenkarlsapalo@admins-MacBook-Pro ~/g/t/thesis-nltk> brew link mysql-connector-c
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.11... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/my_print_defaults
Target /usr/local/bin/my_print_defaults
is a symlink belonging to mysql. You can unlink it:
  brew unlink mysql

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite mysql-connector-c

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run mysql-connector-c

darrenkarlsapalo@admins-MacBook-Pro ~/g/t/thesis-nltk> mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.11 for macos10.13 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

darrenkarlsapalo@admins-MacBook-Pro ~/g/t/thesis-nltk> brew install mysql
Warning: mysql 5.7.22 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 5.7.22, run `brew reinstall mysql`

darrenkarlsapalo@admins-MacBook-Pro ~/g/t/thesis-nltk> brew info openssl
openssl: stable 1.0.2o (bottled) [keg-only]
SSL/TLS cryptography library
https://openssl.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_1 (1,791 files, 12.3MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-04-20 at 13:06:42
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/openssl.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: makedepend ✘
==> Options
--without-test
    Skip build-time tests (not recommended)
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the SystemRoots
keychain. To add additional certificates (e.g. the certificates added in
the System keychain), place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

### Full terminal error log

```
darrenkarlsapalo@admins-MacBook-Pro ~/g/t/thesis-nltk> pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/86/bad31f1c1bb0cc99e88ca2adb7cb5c71f7a6540c1bb001480513de76a931/mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error
  Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/75/hg3nj2sx13567pbv76wdycqm0000gn/T/pip-install-mj5god72/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/75/hg3nj2sx13567pbv76wdycqm0000gn/T/pip-wheel-_frnx3t4 --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o
  _mysql.c:1894:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
                  my_bool recon = reconnect;
                  ^
  _mysql.c:1895:58: error: use of undeclared identifier 'recon'
                  mysql_options(&self->connection, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &recon);
                                                                         ^
  2 errors generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/75/hg3nj2sx13567pbv76wdycqm0000gn/T/pip-install-mj5god72/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/75/hg3nj2sx13567pbv76wdycqm0000gn/T/pip-record-vkhrazcr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:1894:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'my_bool'
                    my_bool recon = reconnect;
                    ^
    _mysql.c:1895:58: error: use of undeclared identifier 'recon'
                    mysql_options(&self->connection, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &recon);
                                                                           ^
    2 errors generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/75/hg3nj2sx13567pbv76wdycqm0000gn/T/pip-install-mj5god72/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/75/hg3nj2sx13567pbv76wdycqm0000gn/T/pip-record-vkhrazcr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/75/hg3nj2sx13567pbv76wdycqm0000gn/T/pip-install-mj5god72/mysqlclient/
```

I'm frustrated enough to want to uninstall all my python installations, but I'm just afraid I might screw something up with Mac that relies on the prebuilt outdated Python version.

How can I get my dependencies to be installed correctly?

Comment: I'm getting this same error with exact same versions of MySQL (8.0.11) and macOS (10.13), but slightly different version of python (3.6.1)

Comment: Worked when I changed to MySQL v5.7.22

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) is not compatible with MySQL 8.0.11 at the time of this writing. Using MySQL v5.7.x will fix this issue (at least on macOS).

Comment: That must have been what I did, because I don't know what I did but my setup got fixed. I must have switched back to MySQL 5.7.x as well. Couldn't write what I did (sorry mate) because I couldn't remember what I did that fixed it.

Comment: `brew uninstall mysql; brew reinstall mysql@5.7; brew pin mysql; brew switch mysql 5.7.22` [remove 8.0.x; make sure 5.7.22 is there; prevent unintentional upgrades beyond 5.7.22; link 5.7.22 as default mysql command].

Comment: Worked, Thanks!

Comment: Due to (I believe) a change in how Brew treats alternate app formulae, `brew pin mysql; brew switch mysql 5.7.22` from medmunds' answer no longer works. You need to run `brew pin mysql@5.7; brew link --overwrite mysql@5.7 --force`, instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using macOS

then can use this command

```
$ LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error:

> Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient Running setup.py
>   bdist_wheel for mysqlclient ... error

While installing myclient using pip then follow the below steps:

1. Download miniconoda (small in size and contains required files)/anacondoa(all)
   [Click to download Miniconda](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)
2. Install it
3. Check the installation using commind "`conda list`" in cmd
4. Run this command then, "`conda install -c miniconda mysqlclient`" this is alternative way to install mysqlclient

Once executed successfully then run again `pip install mysqlclient` , you will find that your sqlclient is already installed successfully.

Hope this will resolve your issue. still not please share the error details. Would love to help.